# RGB function in HTML ? html is scripting language how can it have a function?

Tags: html, colors, rgb, markup

I think markup languages don't have functions in them then what is rgb() ?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall — CSS 1: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units

Comment: ha, shows what I know! We can agree it's CSS though!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, `rgb()` has no special meaning. It is just text.

In CSS, `rgb()` is [a syntax for describing colours](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) and is not a function.

In JavaScript, `rgb()` is a call to a function called `rgb`. This is not a built in function and you have to define it yourself.